# Http Post with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, post, express, connect

I am just trying to write a simple node.js app that will be able to write to a file via post and access that file with the express.static().

```
var express = require('express'),
fs = require('fs')
url = require('url');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));  
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.post('/receieve', function(request, respond) {
    filePath = __dirname + '/public/data.txt';
    fs.appendFile(filePath, request.body) 
});

app.listen(1110);
```

I'm using [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) chrome extension to test if my post is working correctly, but I'm receiving 'cannot POST /receive' when I try to send raw json. Any ideas of what the problem could be? Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo in `app.post('/receieve'`

Comment: Thanks @go-oleg! I don't know how long I looked at this without noticing!

Comment: One of you should post an answer so @user4815162342 can accept and the question can fade away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As go-oleg mentioned, there's a mismatch between the server-side route and the client-side request:

```
'/receive' !== '/receieve' // extra `e` in the route
```

You may also want to specify a format when appending `request.body`. [`Object#toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2), which `appendFile()` will use, simply generates `"[object Object]"`.

```
fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(request.body));
```

And, you should [`.end()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding) the `response` at some point:

```
fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(request.body));
response.end();
```

```
fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(request.body), function () {
    response.end();
});
```

You can also use [`.send()`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send) if you want to include a message in the `response`. It'll call `.end()`.

Comment: Big thanks for the heads up @Jonathan. It's now appending {}, though. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @user4815162342 Express checks the `Content-Type` before parsing: [`if ('application/json' != utils.mime(req)) return next();`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/json.html). So, make sure it's set to [`application/json`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819) in postman (seems you select "Raw" then "JSON" for this).

Comment: Great information @Jonathan. also thanks for the addition of the call back for the response.end(). And I didn't know that send() called .end(). Thank you!